# How can I see the email address and other details entered when users are created?

Tags: users, email

Using Ubuntu 14.4.05

I am logged in as the root user and have sudo access.

There are a number of user accounts currently setup on the system.

How can I view the **full** details about each of these users (via the command line)?

I need to see the information entered when the account was created such as 'Full Name', specifically 'Email Address'. I know the user names.

I tried the `finger <username>` command but it's telling me that `finger` isn't installed. I'd rather achieve this without installing any additional packages.

Comment: Usually 'Email Address' would be entered in the GECOS `other` field, which is part of the user's standard /etc/passwd file entry - have you tried simply using `getent passwd <username>`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `pinky` command instead of `finger`. It is included with the GNU coreutils and should be installed on your system.

Use `pinky -l username` to get all information for a specific user.

There also is a chance that the email is in `/etc/passwd` you can check with `cat /etc/passwd`.